# JQuery call not working on a display form of sharepoint but working on add

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I am using a Script on the CEWP to custumize sharepoint forms.
While the script successfully runs on the default new form, it fails on the default display and default edit

I have noticed that parts of the scripts get executed if I remove the reference to jquery library

P.S.: the script was working fine until it stopped suddenly & it's driving me crazy

The below is the jquery reference I am using

```
<script language="javascript"src="https://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript">
alert('hi');
</script>
```

I am using this script as a testing script

Answer (score 0):

jQuery 1.3.2 is very old. The last release is 1.10.2. Please upgrade your version !

Then, which script are you using? For EditForm and NewForm you could use [SharepointPlus](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/) (with $SP().formfields()), but it won't work for the DispForm (because this one is not really a form but a displayed page).